# dompdf spits out pdf.html in Safari

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I am using dompdf. Everything works great except that safari spits out the file as sample.pdf.html. I worked trough various threads on stackoverflow.  It seems to be content type issue. I have set the content-type to:

text/html; charset=utf-8, application/pdf. Nothing worked out and I am on the end with ideas.

Here is the example file:

```
<?php
require_once("assets/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
$html = ' 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1   /DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/pdf; charset=utf-8">
<style>

</style>
</head> 
</html>';
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
?>
```

Anyone having a clue what the reason could be?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you send the content-type of your page as `application/pdf`? You're setting that in the page you're passing to the renderer, but not in the page you're passing to the client.

```
header('Content-Type: application/pdf`);
```

Comment: I have included: <?php
<?php header('Content-type: application/pdf');?>        
at the top of the file but still no difference.

Answer (score 0):

The meta tag should be

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

And you don't need to set any additionnal header in PHP, dompdf adds them itself.

Comment: its working fine locally, so I assume it has something to do with the remote server setup